# RequireJS + Optimizer Include modules defined on the main file

Tags: requirejs, optimization

I'm using Optimizer for the first time and I am running in some issues or questions.

I'm trying to optimize a main file and it puts, like I've expected, the jQuery, Backbone and Require modules ( and uses then across the whole navigation). But let's say I have a jQuery Plugin that I use on several views. I've tried to add it in the main file using the "include" option on the build.js file. It adds it ( e.g jQuery Slides ) but as I have a view with define("jquery-slides") ( again, an example ) the browser loads the file of the plugin again. Even if it is on the main built file.

Is this suppose to happen? Can I fix this?

Thanks.

Here is some code. Hope it helps =)

**build.js**

```
{
baseUrl: "javascripts/",
appDir: "..",
dir: "dist",
name: "main-site",

include: ['libs/requirejs/require', jquery-slides'],
insertRequire: ['main-site'],

paths: {
    "main-site": 'main-site',
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    'jquery-slides': 'libs/jquery/plugins/slides.min.jquery'

}
}
```

**main-site.js**

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "/javascripts/",
paths: {
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    'underscore': 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    'bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
    'datepicker': 'libs/bootstrap/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker',
    'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone.max',
    'backbone-paginator': 'libs/backbone/plugins/backbone.paginator',
    'backbone-validation': 'libs/backbone/plugins/backbone.validation',
    'text': 'libs/requirejs/text',
    'templates': '/templates/site',
    'views': 'views/site',
    'jquery-cookie': 'libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie',
    'jquery-raty': 'libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.raty.min',
    'jquery-slides': 'libs/jquery/plugins/slides.min.jquery'
},
shim: {
    'backbone-paginator': ['backbone'],
    'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
    'datepicker': ['bootstrap'],
    'jquery-cookies': ['jquery'],
    'jquery-raty': ['jquery'],
    'jquery-slides': ['jquery'],
    'backbone-validation': ['backbone']
}
});

require([
'app-site'
], function(App) {
$(function(){
    App.initialize();
});
});
```

Comment: You should load your full configuration in `build.js`, redeclaring it is long, unecessary and error prone. Next, if `jquery-slide` is required by a module, you shouldn't need to list it in `include`. Only include the module bootstrapping your application. From there dependencies will resolve themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using include I recommend you to declare the modules you want to build. In this way requirejs will package the module and all its dependencies in the optimized bundle.

```
{
    baseUrl: "javascripts/",
    appDir: "..",
    dir: "dist",
    paths: {
        "main-site": 'main-site',
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        'jquery-slides': 'libs/jquery/plugins/slides.min.jquery'
    },
    modules : [
        {
            name : 'main-site',
        }
    ]
}
```

Further considerations:

1. If you have jquery-slides included as a dependency in any of your modules `define(['jquery-slides'], function() {... }` you don't need to use the include directive since all the dependencies of that module will be included in the optimized file

   See the documentation of the modules property in this link

   https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L330
2. Use the property `mainConfigFile` to avoid duplications https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L35

Good luck and I hope this helps you